# hide past timings in dropdown php

Tags: javascript, php

I have a dropdown menu as below

```
 <select name="order_required_time" id="order_required_time" required="">
 <option value="">Choose time</option>
 <option value="11:30 - 12:00 pm">11:30 - 12:00 pm</option>
 <option value="12:00 - 12:30 pm">12:00 - 12:30 pm</option>
 <option value="12:30 - 01:00 pm">12:30 - 01:00 pm</option>
 <option value="01:00 - 01:30 pm">01:00 - 01:30 pm</option>
 <option value="01:30 - 02:00 pm">01:30 - 02:00 pm</option>
 <option value="02:00 - 02:30 pm">02:00 - 02:30 pm</option>
 <option value="02:30 - 03:00 pm">02:30 - 03:00 pm</option>
 <option value="06:30 - 07:00 pm">06:30 - 07:00 pm</option>
 <option value="07:00 - 07:30 pm">07:00 - 07:30 pm</option>
 <option value="07:30 - 08:00 pm">07:30 - 08:00 pm</option>
 <option value="08:00 - 08:30 pm">08:00 - 08:30 pm</option>
 <option value="08:30 - 09:00 pm">08:30 - 09:00 pm</option>
 <option value="09:00 - 09:30 pm">09:00 - 09:30 pm</option>
 </select>
```

when the current time is over, it should not be active in dropdown.
What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're parsing time as a more human readable format rather than a computer readable format, I'd suggest to get the relevant epoch time by using the `strtotime` method of PHP.

So you could get the current time using `$now = strtotime('now');`

Next you could convert each option to time using a similar approach,

```
/*
 * Use some sort of foreach to iterate through all the options of the select tag here
 * Assuming the "value" of the current option is stored in $value inside for loop
 */
$time = strtotime(trim(explode('-',$value)[0]));
if($now > $time){
    //Don't do anything
}
else{
    //Display the option
}
```

A much better option would be to use a form of time easier to parse, epoch for example